# Unable to get width of horizontal RecyclerView [Android, Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recycler view, shown on a card within a vertical scroll view.

I require the width of the recycler view and have tried using the following code:

```kotlin
recyclerView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
val width = recyclerView.measuredWidth
```

This gives me the entire width of the scrollable area, rather than the visible width of the recycler view's bounds. `recyclerView.width` evalutes to zero.

Any suggestions of how to get the visible width of the recycler view element would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: In which method are you executing `recyclerView.width`? Probably the view has not actually been measured and laid out yet at that time. Look into using OnGlobalLayoutListener or OnLayoutChangeListener: https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-ongloballayoutlistener/

Comment: recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()